# Understand Both Byte Order

Tags: c, endianness

Can someone help me to understand the following text:

> Both-byte orders
>
> A numerical value represented by the hexadecimal representation (st uv wx yz) shall be
> recorded in an eight-byte field as (yz wx uv st st uv wx yz).
>
> NOTE:
> For example, the decimal number 305419896 has (12 34 56 78) as its hexadecimal
> representation and is recorded as (78 56 34 12 12 34 56 78).

What does this mean for reading the value ? Do I simply get the 32-bit as an `uint32` and that's all or do I need to convert something in order to get the correct value? Or do I only extract the 4 bytes from the 8 byte field in order to get the value?

EDIT:
Would this work in a union like this?

```
union test
{
   uint64 fullValue;
   uint8  FirstFourBytes[4];
   uint8  SecondFourBytes[4];
}
```

And then I access the `SecondFourBytes` Array to get the correct value.

Comment: With a union, the arrays overlap.  They don't stack up, so FirstFourBytes and SecondFourBytes will contain the exact same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The byte order refers to the order in which the individual bytes that make up a larger data type (such as a 32-bit integer) are stored in memory.

Traditionally a 32-bit integer is written out either in [Little Endian or Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order in memory, taking up 4 bytes (32 bits) but it looks like in your case the protocol dictates that the integer be stored in both Little Endian and Big Endian order one after each other, doubling the space required for storage to 64 bits.

When reading, you will have to take into account that the value uses 8 bytes, and you can read  either the first 4 bytes (little endian), or the last 4 bytes (big endian), depending on which endianness (byte order) your platform uses.

When writing, you will have to serialize both versions, writing out the little endian representation first, followed by the big endian representation.

**UPDATE 2**

Your modified union would still not work because you are now attempting to create a union between a `uint64` presumably 64-bit data type and two other arrays, each taking 4 bytes (32 bits).

```
// this is not right
union test
{
   uint64 fullValue;
   uint8  FirstFourBytes[4];   // this points to the first 4 bytes
   uint8  SecondFourBytes[4];  // .. despite name, this also points to the first 4 bytes
}
```

However, you could use a union like this:

```
union test
{
   uint64 fullValue;              // although this is probably useless to you
   struct Raw
   {
      uint8  LittleEndianBytes[4];
      uint8  BigEndianBytes[4];
   };
}
```

Comment: First: Thank you very much for your help. I am still not sure if I understand the difference between your code and my code. What does the struct do differently ?

Comment: @JeckyPorter - You're welcome. The struct stores the two arrays sequentially, one after the other. The union is more like an alias, for the same memory location.

Comment: @JeckyPorter The difference is that a union is only as large as the largest member... so in your union you have 3 values starting at the same address, where in miky's you have 3 valuesm, full value and littleEndianBytes start at the same address, and BigEndian starts 4 bytes later.

Comment: You don't really need the union. In this case a single struct is all you need. You just need to write the code to map a 32-bit integer to and from the struct, manually.