# Bin file differs from memory map

Tags: memory, stm32, bin, flash-memory

I read some where that in stm32 .bin file reflects exactly as it is in flash but when I compare my flash content(by using cube Programmer) & .bin file(which is generated by keil IDE), they were different from each other?

do any one know why they are different?

[Flash contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff3ep.png)
[Bin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcDnc.png)

Comment: After some try I find out when select data width to 8-bit in cube programmer, it shows exactly what I see in bin file but if I select 16-bit or 32-bit they will be different.What is the reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand Both Byte Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279017/understand-both-byte-order)

Comment: yes i confused with different representation of same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is always the same.

This is a little-endian platform so when you display it as words the digits are in a different order to when you display it as bytes.